# Math power rounding issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to move decimal places around a number.
I have the following set up.

```
dividend = 9130.124;
numFactor = 1;
dividend = (dividend * Math.pow(10, numFactor));
```

I get the following result

```
91301.23999999999
```

I thought I would get something like

```
91301.24
```

If I change the dividend to `9130.123`

I get the correct answer `91301.23`

Is there a way around this or am i missing something?

Comment: use this to get the result.. Math.round(dividend * 100) / 100

Comment: I think Wesley wants to move decimal places around the number. All answers were about rounding it to a fixed no of decimal places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your dividend is 9130.12399999... So you have to use divided.toFixed() before changing it..

```
dividend = 9130.12399999
dividend.toFixed(3); // here dividend will be 9130.124
numFactor = 1;
dividend = (dividend * Math.pow(10, numFactor));
```

You will get 91301.24

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.ceil(91301.23999999999*100)/100 // = 91301.24
```

Answer (score 1):

use .toFixed(2) to Round the value to two digits.

```
dividend = dividend.toFixed(2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tamilmani/LR79p/

Answer (score 1):

```
dividend=9130.124;
numFactor=1;
dp=3;
dividend = (dividend * Math.pow(10,numFactor));
dividend = Math.round(dividend * Math.pow(10,dp) + 0.5) / Math.pow(10, dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Big.js](https://github.com/whatgoodisaroad/Big-js) which is an arbitrary precision math library for Javascript.

Then your [code becomes](http://jsfiddle.net/wsdookadr/XDTgX/):

```
var dividend = new Big("9130.124");
dividend = dividend.times(new Big(""+Math.pow(10,1)));
console.log(dividend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    dividend = 9130.124345;
    dividend = dividend.toString();
    numFactor = 2;//can be changed as u need


    var indx = dividend.indexOf( '.' );


    dividend = dividend.replace( /\./g, "" );//remove .
    dividend = dividend.substring( 0, indx + numFactor ) + '.' +
                        dividend .substring( indx + numFactor, dividend.length );
```

Works fine with any value for numFactor. And no need for additional libraries